# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'n' in list of class objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Oh that's true. And now that code works but my long code still doesn't. Here it is https://pastebin.com/Z4qjGxCU. The problem with this one is that, when I call check_num() on the tiles, it works. But when I call check_mouse(), load_image() [which I've commented so you don't have to download the assets] or print_tile() they return an error such as this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sergio\Desktop\Minesweeper\minesweeper.py", line 96, in <module>
    grid[i][j].check_mouse()
AttributeError: 'Tile' object has no attribute 'check_mouse'
```

I've checked the code but I can't find anything that's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you are trying to create a class (unless pygame has some syntax I don't know about), but that's the wrong syntax.  Try replacing `def A()` with `class A:`

Comment: Please don't edit the question if you've got another problem. Just post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class with `class A:` instead of `def A()`